# Estimator variance for L1 norm and L2 norm

Tags: statistics

I am reading an image processing paper [robust super-resolution image reconstruction](http://www.asp.eurasipjournals.com/content/pdf/1687-6180-2007-034821.pdf). In this paper, it uses some basic knowledge from robust statistics. One fact it quotes in the paper is:

> For normally distributed data, L1 norm produces an estimator with higher variance than the optimal L^2 (quadratic) norm

Could someone explain the reason? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the most important part of that sentence: "**For normally distributed data**, the L1 norm produces estimates with higher variance than the optimal L2 (quadratic) norm."

Comment: @Axoren Changed as you have suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When normalized, normally-distributed data in $n$-dimensional space can be seen as a really fuzzy $n$-ball with a center $\vec \mu$ and a soft-boundary square-distance $\sigma_i^2$ away from the center.

You can double check this with visualization tools: Sample points from a normal distribution in two or three dimensions and watch how they form a point-cloud that looks more than vaguely like a sphere.

Because of this, the $L2$ norm works wonders. As part of the cost function, it enforces that we're trying to tightly pack a ball, with a regularizing term enforcing that we don't pack the ball too tightly.

If we use $L1$, the shape of the "ball" we're packing changes shape, it becomes a contents of a simplex. You can think of a simplex as the largest $n$-cube that is contained in an $n$-cube of same major radius. This leads to higher variance immediately since a ball in $L2$ norm is the same shape as our variance already and we're trying to pack the same data into a smaller space.

Because of the difference in shapes of the balls in these norms. We'll either be left with a lot of empty space at the corners of the simplex or a saturation of points outside of the faces of the simplex. Our error will always be larger than the $n$-ball of the the $L2$ norm which the already round data can snuggly fit inside of.

Comment: Side note: With this understanding, you can now see what it's important that you specified "normally distributed". You can construct an arbitrary dataset for which it's data conforms to the shape of a simplex and nicely fits with the $L1$ norm over the $L2$ norm.

Comment: This is such an interesting explanation of the l1/l2 norms' relationship to the variance of an estimator.. can i ask how you developed it? what did you study to build up to this? this is a gem of an explanation.